# using file:serialize to write files with eXist db

Tags: database, file, serialization, exist-db

I'm trying to use the file:serialize function to write some content to a file using eXist-db.

Here's the code I'm using, it's just a login and the call of the serialize function.
someFunction just returns a node with some content.

> let $null := xdb:login("/db",
>   "****", "****"),
>          $someBool := file:serialize(local:someFunction(),"test.txt","")

The very helpful error I'm getting is:

> Error found
>
> Message: Error null

I'm using version 1.4.0 on Ubuntu, and I enabled the file module (and built it). What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem like OP.
Turns out your third parameter to the serialize function is wrong.

This:

```
$someBool := file:serialize(local:getSomething(),"test.txt","")
```

Should be this:

```
$someBool := file:serialize(local:getSomething(),"test.txt",())
```

As the third parameter has to be a sequence, not a string.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
let $null := xdb:login("/db", "*", "*")
```

First, let's rule something out: the 2nd and 3rd parameters should be the username and password of a dba user.  See the docs for [xmldb:login()](http://demo.exist-db.org/exist/functions/xmldb/login) and [file:serialize()](http://demo.exist-db.org/exist/functions/file/serialize).

Comment: Yes I know, but for this example on stackoverflow I replaced them with stars.

Comment: Okay, good.  Next: is this your entire query?  Do you have a "return" clause?  A "let" without a "return" is an orphaned expression.  If you've got a complete query, can you simplify the file:serialize() by replacing it with, say, <x/>?  Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

This is the function in which I want to write the file, so I'm just trying to write some test content:

```
declare function local:getSomething() as node(){
    let $s := "something"
    return
        <test>{$s}</test>
};
declare function local:mainPage() as node()?
{
   let $null := xdb:login("/db", "*", "*"),
       $someBool := file:serialize(local:getSomething(),"test.txt","") 
   return
    <test>Succes!</test>
};
```